# IntelliJ How is a File considered Edited (⌘E-⌘E)?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When pressing ⌘E on macOS, IntelliJ will [show recent files](https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/tips/jump-to-recent-files/). When pressing ⌘E a second time, IntelliJ combines this with a filter to list only edited files.

[image: Show Edited only]

However, this begs the question: what makes a file edited?

I have dozens of files being listed when I press ⌘E-⌘E when `git status` only lists a couple of files. There is [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277377/Show-edited-only-option-in-Recent-Files-lists-some-unmodified-files), so I am not sure what I am seeing is intended behaviour.

Comment: Edited file is the one that has different from previous version. E.g. IDE marks file edited in cache when you type something inside editor.

Comment: @Justinas so you are saying if all code is my own, show edited only will not help at all? This seems odd. The "All Changes Files" tool window is appropriately showing all changed files since last commit according to git.